# Loss of bindings after starting program from another with args

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

This is part of code in first programm, where I starts second program.

```
        private void ExecuteStartCacherCommand(object parameter)
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("\"" + ProductCode.BoxName + "\""); sb.Append(" ");
                sb.Append(LengthText); sb.Append(" ");
                sb.Append(WidthText); sb.Append(" ");
                sb.Append(HeightText); sb.Append(" ");
                sb.Append(L1); sb.Append(" ");
                sb.Append(L2); sb.Append(" ");
                sb.Append(StampTotalPrice);

                string arg = sb.ToString();

                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "CacherPrices.exe";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
                p.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is part of the code in second program.

```
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            try
            {
                string[] args = new string[10];

                ArgsIncome ai;

                if (e.Args.Length > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < e.Args.Length; i++)
                    {
                        args[i] = e.Args[i];
                    }

                    ai = ArgsIncome.getSampleOfDataBase();
                    ai.Name = args[0];
                    ai.Length = args[1];
                    ai.Width = args[2];
                    ai.Height = args[3];
                    ai.L1 = args[4];
                    ai.L2 = args[5];
                    ai.Stamp = args[6];

                }
                else
                    ai = ArgsIncome.getSampleOfDataBase(); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


            // загружаем главное окно.
            View.MainWindow window = new View.MainWindow();
            this.MainWindow = window;
            window.Show();

        }
```

**Problem:**
When I start second program from the first one, **all binding that I have is gone**.
When I start second program in debug with args, everything is O.K.
When I comment args sending in first program and start second without them, everything is O.K.

Additional info

```
public class ArgsIncome
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Length { get; set; }
        public string Width { get; set; }
        public string Height { get; set; }
        public string L1 { get; set; }
        public string L2 { get; set; }
        public string Stamp { get; set; }

        private ArgsIncome()
        {
            Name = "Тип";
            Length = "0";
            Width = "0";
            Height = "0";
            L1 = "0";
            L2 = "0";
            Stamp = "0";
        }

        private static readonly object padlock = new object();
        private static ArgsIncome dataBase = null;

        public static ArgsIncome getSampleOfDataBase()
        {
            if (dataBase == null)
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (dataBase == null)
                    {
                        dataBase = new ArgsIncome();
                    }
                }
            }
            return dataBase;
        }
    }
```

Example of bindings

```
<TextBox Margin="5" Width="75" Text="{Binding Path=StampPrice,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

string _stampPrice;
    public string StampPrice
    {
        get
        {
            if (_stampPrice == null)
                _stampPrice = _ai.Stamp;
            return _stampPrice;
        }
        set
        {
            _stampPrice = value;
        }
    }

class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase{}

public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable{}
```

Comment: Or recommend how to do so: program can be opened from .exe and can be opened from another program by button press with data sent

Comment: Where exactly you start the second program? I might be missing something.

Comment: I start second in first by button press ""private void ExecuteStartCacherCommand(object parameter)""

Comment: And how do you intend to to use the *ai* object? You're setting its properties, but it will be removed after the scope of the *try* block ends. (I'm talking about the second example of course)

Comment: This is Singleton class. Example of use is in VievModel some properties is set by its data. string _stampPrice;
        public string StampPrice
        {
            get
            {
                if (_stampPrice == null)
                    _stampPrice = _ai.Stamp;
                return _stampPrice;
            }
            set
            {
                _stampPrice = value;
            }
        }

Comment: Sure, but you have to realise, that you create your *ai* object in the *try* block and it will be removed after the *try* block finishes. You don't use it inside the block, so your values are simply ignored.

Comment: You mean, *Singleton*?

Comment: The problem is not in receiving data, all data is received and properties is set by it. But problem is in bindings.

Comment: Well, of course the problem is in the bindings as you are not binding anything (your *ai* object which holds all the incoming properties simply gets disposed).

Comment: *Or you'r not posting the whole code.

Comment: Can I make fotos in order to insure you that data is sent and all properties is set by data?  http://postimg.org/image/n7cncxyll/   http://postimg.org/image/wsif4q86j/

Comment: Added Singleton code.

Comment: Oo Brutal code... What do you mean by all bindings are gone? I'm assuming that you mean that the values are not set and never be updated, which cannot be updated since you're not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: A cannot input here all the code. It is implements INotifyPropertyChanged.   By all bindings are gone I mean that properties is set and after this is not updated. And please pay attention I wrote ""When I start second program in debug with args, everything is O.K.""

Comment: Well I guess, that it's something in the initialization order, but it's difficuilt to tell, because of the mess in your post. And since the setter of your `StampPrice` code doesn't contain a `RaisePropertyChanged` method or something similar, I assumed that the class don't implement it... A suggestion, please clean up your post and show us the essential parts. E.g. at least a partial implementation of your `ArgsIncome` class, and much more important the implementation of your VM and its usage in the xaml.

Comment: Thank you for help. I found problem. It was in incoming args. There was double value sended by "0.00" and TryParse do not want to work with "." just with ",".  Sory for bothering you.